# "autostart" from screenrc

Tags: configuration, gnu-screen

How can I start some command for certain tabs in screen automatically?

I've tried using command directly (screen mc) but it seem to load with broken environment or terminal profile. I've also tried using `stuff` command which seems to do what I need except for missing enter: if I write `stuff mc` I see letters `mc` in correct tab, but in order to execute it I have to press <kbd>enter</kbd> manually. Is there way to do it automatically? Or, for C programmers, what's the `stuff` equivalent for `\n`?

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

```
screen [-opts] [n] [cmd [args]|//group]
```

So to run `mc` on startup, your `.screenrc` should contain at least

```
screen mc
```

If your terminal settings are broken, it may be that your system does not contain a entry for screen in the terminal database.  In this case, you could try telling it to treat screen as a VT100 with this alternate configuration file:

```
term vt100
screen mc
```